# "errorMessage": "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have this code here to be deployed over AWS.
and my issue in the testing over AWS as follows:

When I pass values to x as follows:

"x": 1.0 or "x": 100.0 ....etc (the fraction part is zero)
It seen as integer and error said  "errorMessage": "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double" in this line x_Ptr[i] = str.get(i).doubleValue();

If x pass with fraction like "x": 1.5 or "x":0.444 it works

Any advice here?

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, ApiGatewayResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Handler.class);

    @Override
    public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
        LOG.info("received: " + event);

        List<Double> str = new ArrayList<Double>();

        str = (ArrayList<Double>)(event.get("x"));
        double[] x_Ptr = new double[str.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < x_Ptr.length; i++) {
            x_Ptr[i] = str.get(i).doubleValue();
        }

        System.out.println(x_Ptr[0]);

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Output bodyout = new Output(x_Ptr);

        return ApiGatewayResponse.builder()
                .setStatusCode(200)
                .setObjectBody(bodyout)
                .setHeaders(headers)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but because you're only calling `.doubleValue()`, can you get away with casting to `ArrayList<Number>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Define a POJO for the input type, the problem is the type information is not available when deserializing and it is inferred from the data.

```
class MyPojo {
  List<Double> x;
}

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<MyPojo, ApiGatewayResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Handler.class);

    @Override
    public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(MyPojo event, Context context) {
        // event.x is now a list of doubles
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ollik1, It works with PoJo and I can test the Lambdha function. but when I create an API gateway the HTTP return internal error.